# BigCartel - embedded code from youtube video problem

Tags: youtube, bigcartel

am not a code expert and know very little. I created my own Youtube video, and copied the embedded code into a page in my Bigcartel website. What I want is the (Share, Watch Later, & Watch On Youtube links to disappear). Below is a copy of the current embedded code derived from my BigCartel website page. Also attached is a picture of the Youtube video from my BigCartel website that shows the links i want to disappear. [youtube video pic showing unwanted links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7grC.png)

If someone can add whatever needs to be added to the code in their response and I will simply copy the code and paste it into the BigCartel Page. Any help to get these links removed would be appreciated.  Code is noted below.

This tutorial and educational video will demonstrate information about our service, and how to use our service.  Thank you for visiting!

Logged on youtube page and disabled some options but that doesn't seem to remove the (Share, Watch Later, & Watch On Youtube) links from the YouTube video embedded into my BigCartel website page.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.